# htmlhelp.lib for Visual Studio 2012 MFC app?

Tags: mfc, visual-studio-2012, html-help

Anyone know of 3rd party or open source alternatives to MS' old htmlhelp.lib library?  It was compiled w/ an older version of Visual Studio and apparently is no longer supported.
I'm porting an old program to VS.2012.

Looks like the official way to do this is a bit hackish...you have to create a new app w/ HTML help using the MFC Wizard and then merge all your old code into it :-P
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/vcgeneral/thread/045a2e45-01cb-4be3-afc5-f1473496760f/

EDIT: Note: my app is 64-bit..

Comment: It was just removed from the wizard.  The import library is still available, C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.0\Lib\win8\um\x86\htmlhelp.lib

Comment: my app is 64-bit unfortunately.  Weird that they would include that htmllib for 32-bit apps, but not 64-bit ones :-P

Comment: It is not that weird, ancient libraries are retired by just not porting them to 64-bit.  Everybody displays help in a browser these days.

Comment: Seems like they should just say that outright in the release notes or something...looks like this has been in place since Visual Studio 2010 :-P
And I still say the official way to add it to an old app is hackish :-)